# Running powershell like a process to monitor for event changes

Tags: windows, windows-7, powershell, windows-8

I would like to have powershell manage network profiles for me depending on where I connect to. Mostly for my three work locations I jump between. I need specific IP off the wireless networks so I can access our servers.

With powershell I can run the scripts to pull SSIDs and then configure the network to set static IPs but is there a way to have powershell monitor for these changes and then set the networks?

EDIT: Can this also be ran in the background so no window needs to be left up?

Comment: Please update with your research efforts and/or what you've tried thus far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a script with a never-ending loop like this:

```
do
{
    # check whatever you want to check and react to it...

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 30

} until ($false)
```

Press CRTL+C to terminate